# Собрать побайтово UDP пакет (используя QByteArray) и послать серверу

Tags: qt, сокет, udp, пакет

Помогите сформировать QByteArray, чтоб передать его серверу stun.ekiga.net в UDP-дейтаграмме. Приложение, написанное мною на основе любезно предоставленной мне помощи, посылает только пустые запросы и при этом не определяющиеся Wireshark'ом в качестве запросов по STUN-протоколу, увы.. Пакет должен выглядеть так: [right-request-to-stun http://img-host.org.ua/images/1vlv.png](http://img-host.org.ua/images/1vlv.png)
А посылаемый моим приложением выглядит так: [my-wrong-request http://img-host.org.ua/images/2hlh.png](http://img-host.org.ua/images/2hlh.png)
Причём так происходит даже когда я использовал .. Полагаю, неверно использовал. Поэтому отказался от функций вроде qToBigEndian и qFromBigEndian - и стал просто добавлять нужные поля, предварительно переведя их в двоичный вид. Вот так стал в итоге выглядеть мой код, опять-таки, неработающий:

```
UdpToStun::UdpToStun(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
   port = 3478;
   sock = new QUdpSocket();
   lstd = new QUdpSocket();
   connect(lstd, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(read()));
   lstd->bind(QHostAddress::Any, port); // хочу и ответ же получить, вот и открываю слушающий сокет
   QByteArray ba;
   ba.append(0x1); // Тип запроса: 1 - binding request
   ba.append(0x0); // Тип сообщения: 0 - reguest
   ba.append(100001000100101010010001000010); // Это бинарное представление magic cookie, они у STUN'а по стандарту всегда равны 0x2112A442
   sock->writeDatagram(ba, QHostAddress("217.10.68.152"), port);
}
```

Comment: Первый и второй байт, судя по шаблону на первом скрине, записаны верно. Проблема, получается, возникает далее. Почему в `QByteArray` Вы записываете огромное целое вместо `0x2112A442`?

Comment: @alexis031182, Нет, к сожалению, первые два байта так же неверно записаны, как и все последующие (по поводу них: они ложатся как БИТЫ в 1-ю и 2-ю позицию байта №1, а уже начиная с байта №2 идёт "набивка" числа 0x2112A442). А как раз нужно, чтоб было так, как вы и предположили. Я за прошедший день уже перепробовал много разных способов послать "укомплектованную" дейтаграмму STUN-серверу, но не преуспел в этом..

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что проблема в типе пересылаемых чисел. Я подсмотрел [на гитхабе](https://github.com/maoxuli/stunclient) один из проектов, что реализован без использования Qt и там шлются 16-битные беззнаковые целые. Пробовали ли Вы отправлять данные через `QDataStream` соответствующего типа? `QDataStream` по умолчанию формирует данные в `Big Endian Order`, что и требуется, исходя из описания протокола.

По идее, код формирования запроса должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
QByteArray data;

{
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream << quint16(0x1) << quint16(0x0) << quint32(0x2112A442);
}

sock->writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress("217.10.68.152"), port);
```

Если такой вариант не пройдёт, то, наверное, имеет смысл воспользоваться методом `QDataStream::writeRawData(const char *s, int len)`, произведя конвертацию чисел самостоятельно, по типу того, как это реализовано, например, в том проекте, ссылку на который я вставил чуть выше.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48452/discussion-on-answer-by-alexis031182---udp---qbyt).